# How to find number of permutations of 1-N length, each [1-N] with k values

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

This imaginary problem involves a vector of length 5, with each value to be selected from a unique range of values.

A real-world example might include 5 different single-digit combination locks.

How many different ways could I lock a single gate, assuming that I can use any number of locks?

Assuming that each lock takes values `([1-3], [1-3], [1-3], [1-3], [1-3])` There would be `3^5 ==  243` possible combinations. But I'm also interested in calculating the total number of combinations possible by using subsets of the 5 locks, so adding the solution for each *combination* of four locks, each combination of 3 locks and so on. The solution would also ideally be generalisable so that each list of values can differ i.e. `([1-2], [1-10], [A-C] ... )`

Does there exist a mathematical solution to this problem?

---

edit:

In the main, the question is about a general purpose mathematical solution. For example, to find the number of combination of a set of length (3), one uses `3!` ie. 6 combinations of [1,2,3].

I was wondering if there exists a general purpose solution to the above scenario. If not, I would think it could be possible to program something to recurse over the possibilities, which I guess is why I decided to post it here first as my search for a mathematical solution came up empty handed.

---

Some examples of inputs and outputs as requested:

input = [A,B,C] [1,2,3,4,5] [G,H]

output combinations are all possible combinations of those three lists, without needing to sample all three lists. Note combinations, hence [A1G] == [G1A]

i.e. (this is not all the combinations):
A
B
C
A1
A2
A3
...
C4
C5
A1G
A1H
A2G
A2H
...
C5G
C5H
...
1
2
3
4
5
1G
1H
.
.
5G
5H
..
G
H

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. But, since you ask for a _mathematical_ solution and this is the _computer science_ section of Stack Exchange, I think your question is off-topic.

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking. Can you give a few sample input/output pairs?

Comment: @DavidRicherby Do you think the question is clear enough to be migrated to [math.SE]? Yuval doesn't seem to think so.

Comment: @Raphael I've no strong opinion about whether we should migrate. Math.se is a big site so one more question probably wouldn't make much difference to them. Ideally, the asker will clarify and we can make a decision then.

Comment: I'm not sure this comment thread is well-suited for extended discussion about whether this question is on-topic; it might be better to take this to [meta] by posting a question there.   For background, I'll link to [our existing policy](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/704/755) on which kinds of math questions are considered on-topic here. (Cc: @fade2black)  JohnL_10, do you feel this question is best answered by computer scientists?  If so, it might help to explain why in the question.  Regardless, please do edit the question to clarify what you are asking.

Comment: @D.W. I think we should wait for asker's response, and then moderators should decide. I have no objections to moderators's decision.

Comment: Thanks, @fade2black.  Personally, I'd prefer to see the community decide; that typically happens by voting (among those with reputation to vote to close/reopen), or by discussion on [meta].  In any case, it seems the first order of business is for the question to be edited so we can understand what is being asked -- otherwise we're all guessing what exactly the question is.

Comment: Hi all, thanks for the attention to this post and apologies for the lack of clarity. Adding some comments and edits now.

Comment: I think your use of the word *permutation* is confusing here. First you ask for all permutations of combinations, but when you say [A1G] == [G1A] it seems like what you really want is all *combinations* of combinations.

Comment: Please edit your question to ask for an algorithm to generate the possibilities. Then your question belongs here. And it's what my accepted answer does :),

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Your lock values are all distinct. We could instead consider the locks distinct.)

We add a `nil` value to each lock, representing the lock *not* being included. Using your example, we get ...

```
input = [A,B,C,nil] [1,2,3,4,5,nil] [G,H,nil]
```

... to choose from. There are ...

$$4 \times 6 \times 3 = 72 $$

... ways to do this.

In general, from sets $Locks$, there are ...(

$$\prod_{l \in Locks} (\vert l \vert + 1)$$

... ways.

---

So far, so mathematical. Now let's generate the possibilities. I'll have to use a programming language. My choice is Clojure, a Lisp. We should be able to at least verify the above result.

```
(def locks '[[A,B,C] [1,2,3,4,5] [G,H]])

(defn combos [ls]
  (if (empty? ls)
    [()]
    (let [[l & ls] ls
          sub-list (combos ls)]
      (concat
        sub-list
        (for [x l, y sub-list] (cons x y))))))
```

Now

```
(count (combos locks))
=> 72
```

... as expected.

There are better ways to depict the problem space, but this'll surely do.

Comment: Using Nil values would solve this problem. Thank you for the answer!